# Want to load javascript for mobile devices only

Tags: javascript, html

> I want to show these 4 buttons in a row in desktop mode
> and show carousel like this only for mobile view[image]
> The first pic is for mobile view and the second pic is for pc view
> Here is the link to my code https://jsfiddle.net/FODraciel/wehc8ryv/4/
> I am trying with javascript and tried some steps which were set width technique but it does not work. Any idea of how to do it?
> I have tried some steps like this

```
window.onload=function(){
w = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth || window.innerWidth;
var targetWidth = 768;
if ( w >= targetWidth) {     
  //Add your javascript for screens wider than or equal to 768 here
}
else {
  //Add your javascript for screens smaller than 768 here
}
```

};

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to detect a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem, there's probably much more efficient solution to your actual problem than load different scripts depending on screen width of the client (which can be changed during a session). Take a look at CSS solutions and [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries).